# How to plot ROC Curve for multiclass data and measure MAUC from confusion matrix

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, roc, confusion-matrix

I have used back propagation on a dataset which has 3 classes: L, B, R. I have also made a confusion matrix after making the neural network.

Actual class array:

```
sample_test = array([0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int64)
```

Predicted class array:

```
yp = array([0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int64)
```

Code for confusion matrix:

```
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.utils.multiclass import unique_labels

class_names = ['B','R','L']

def plot_confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, classes,
                          normalize=False,
                          title=None,
                          cmap=plt.cm.Blues):
    """
    This function prints and plots the confusion matrix.
    Normalization can be applied by setting `normalize=True`.
    """
    if not title:
        if normalize:
            title = 'Normalized confusion matrix'
        else:
            title = 'Confusion matrix, without normalization'

    # Compute confusion matrix
    cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
    # Only use the labels that appear in the data
    classes = [0, 1, 2]
    if normalize:
        cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
        print("Normalized confusion matrix")
    else:
        print('Confusion matrix, without normalization')

    print(cm)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    im = ax.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    ax.figure.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
    # We want to show all ticks...
    ax.set(xticks=np.arange(cm.shape[1]),
           yticks=np.arange(cm.shape[0]),
           # ... and label them with the respective list entries
           xticklabels=classes, yticklabels=classes,
           title=title,
           ylabel='True label',
           xlabel='Predicted label')

    # Rotate the tick labels and set their alignment.
    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right",
             rotation_mode="anchor")

    # Loop over data dimensions and create text annotations.
    fmt = '.2f' if normalize else 'd'
    thresh = cm.max() / 2.
    for i in range(cm.shape[0]):
        for j in range(cm.shape[1]):
            ax.text(j, i, format(cm[i, j], fmt),
                    ha="center", va="center",
                    color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")
    fig.tight_layout()
    return ax

np.set_printoptions(precision=2)

# Plot non-normalized confusion matrix
plot_confusion_matrix(sample_test, yp, classes=class_names, 
                      title='Confusion matrix, without normalization')

# Plot normalized confusion matrix
plot_confusion_matrix(sample_test, yp, classes=class_names , normalize=True,
                      title='Normalized confusion matrix')

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]
[image]

Now I want to plot ROC curve for this and calculate MAUC. I saw the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html#example-model-selection-plot-roc-py) but cant understand properly what to do.

I will be very grateful, if anyone can help me by giving some suggestions how to do that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The ROC is calculated per class - treat each class as the "positive" class and the other classes as the "negative" classes. Note - first you will have to use predict_proba() - to get the predicted probability per class. Something like this:

```
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
X = iris.drop('species',axis=1)
y = iris['species']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y)

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(y_train)
le.transform(y_train)

model = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=1)
model.fit(X_train,le.transform(y_train))

predictions =pd.DataFrame(model.predict_proba(X_test),columns=list(le.inverse_transform(model.classes_)))

print(roc_auc_score((y_test == 'versicolor').astype(float), predictions['versicolor']))
```

Comment: This value is for 1 class. Am I right? then how can I get the auc value for others class and how to combine them to calculate MAUC? can you provide me any documentation? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Look at https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/780d/a873883986aa100c17e55110d51df06ae50f.pdf (equation 3) you can use the formula there for combining the pairwise AUCs

Comment: @RoeeAnuar equation 3 refers to pairwise class AUC (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.auc.html) and NOT roc_auc_score (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html)

Comment: @arilwan the ROC score is for one vs. all

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second question to calculate the Multiclass AUC, there are open source implementations for it. Specifically, such  solutions implement equations 3 and 7 of [Hand and Till 2001](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1023/A:1010920819831.pdf) original paper.

Take a look at this solution:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

# pairwise class AUC
def a_value(y_true, y_pred_prob, zero_label=0, one_label=1):
    """
    Approximates the AUC by the method described in Hand and Till 2001,
    equation 3.
    
    NB: The class labels should be in the set [0,n-1] where n = # of classes.
    The class probability should be at the index of its label in the predicted
    probability list.
    
    Args:
        y_true: actual labels of test data 
        y_pred_prob: predicted class probability
        zero_label: label for positive class
        one_label: label for negative class
    Returns:
        The A-value as a floating point.
    """
    
    idx = np.isin(y_true, [zero_label, one_label])
    labels = y_true[idx]
    prob = y_pred_prob[idx, zero_label]
    sorted_ranks = labels[np.argsort(prob)]
    
    n0, n1, sum_ranks = 0, 0, 0
    n0 = np.count_nonzero(sorted_ranks==zero_label)
    n1 = np.count_nonzero(sorted_ranks==one_label)
    sum_ranks = np.sum(np.where(sorted_ranks==zero_label)) + n0

    return (sum_ranks - (n0*(n0+1)/2.0)) / float(n0 * n1)  # Eqn 3 of the original paper


def MAUC(y_true, y_pred_prob, num_classes):
    """
    Calculates the MAUC over a set of multi-class probabilities and
    their labels. This is equation 7 in Hand and Till's 2001 paper.
    
    NB: The class labels should be in the set [0,n-1] where n = # of classes.
    The class probability should be at the index of its label in the
    probability list.
    
    Args:
        y_true: actual labels of test data 
        y_pred_prob: predicted class probability
        zero_label: label for positive class
        one_label: label for negative class
        num_classes (int): The number of classes in the dataset.
    
    Returns:
        The MAUC as a floating point value.
    """
    # Find all pairwise comparisons of labels
    class_pairs = [x for x in itertools.combinations(range(num_classes), 2)]

    # Have to take average of A value with both classes acting as label 0 as this
    # gives different outputs for more than 2 classes
    sum_avals = 0
    for pairing in class_pairs:
        sum_avals += (a_value(y_true, y_pred_prob, zero_label=pairing[0], one_label=pairing[1]) +
                      a_value(y_true, y_pred_prob, zero_label=pairing[1], one_label=pairing[0])) / 2.0

    return sum_avals * (2 / float(num_classes * (num_classes-1)))  # Eqn 7 of the original paper
```

Credit: [Pritom Saha Akash](https://github.com/pritomsaha/Multiclass_AUC/blob/master/multiclass_auc.py)